# Finding common characters in strings

Tags: php, string, compare

I am tring this method to find the common characters in two strings namely, $a and $r, but the first character isn't getting printed . Moreover the $already collects the common characters and prevents them from being printed for multiple times( I need each character to be printed once only) but it isn't doing so. Please tell me what errors I am making.

```
<?php
$a="BNJUBCI CBDIDIBO";
$r="SBKJOJLBOU";
$already="";
for($i=0;$i<strlen($r);$i++)
{
   if (stripos($a,$r[$i])!=FALSE)
   {
        if (stripos($already,$r[$i])==FALSE)
        {
            $already=$already.$r[$i];
            echo "already=".$already."<br>";
            echo $r[$i]."<br>";
        }
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `!==FALSE` instead of `!=FALSE`. The problem is that `stripos` returns 0 if the needle is at the start of the haystack, and 0 is falsy. By using `!==` you are forcing it to ensure the result is actually false, and not just 0.

This is actually listed in the [docs](http://php.net/stripos). An "RTM" might be appropriate here.

> **Warning**
>   This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Comment: Thanks.
For correcting the error with $already , I had to put === in place of ==.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to find the intersection of the two strings in PHP is to turn them into arrays and use the built-in functions for that purpose.

The following will show all the unique and common characters between the two strings.

```
<?php
    $a="BNJUBCI CBDIDIBO";
    $r="SBKJOJLBOU";

    $a_arr = str_split($a);
    $r_arr = str_split($r);

    $common = implode(array_unique(array_intersect($a_arr, $r_arr)));

    echo "'$common'";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think a much simpler solution to this would be to make the strings into arrays and compare those no?

Something like:

```
<?php
$a="BNJUBCI CBDIDIBO";
$r="SBKJOJLBOU";

$shared = implode( '' , array_intersect( str_split($a) , str_split($r) ) );
?>
```

That should return you a string of all the characters in $a that are present in $r

Comment: check str1 = raahul
str2 = parul
final = raaul There are two 'a' occurence while it should be one..