# PHP: Return identical consecutive characters between two strings

Tags: php, similarity

I want to get the similar string between two barcode inputs.

1st Barcode :**QW1234560**
2nd Barcode: **ABW12345-01-A5**
Output should be: **W12345**

I tried **similar_text**, but it only returns the number of strings and the percentage of the matched string.

Then I tried:

```
<?php
    $barcode_before ="QW1234560";
    $barcode_after  ="ABW12345-01-A5";

    $before         = str_split($barcode_before);
    $after          = str_split($barcode_after);

    $matched_string = implode(array_unique(array_intersect($before, $after)));

    echo $matched_string;
?>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9878761/3208549)

But the output I'm getting is : **0W12345**

Comment: Are you looking for similar characters, or for identical consecutive characters?

Comment: You can try with the Levenshtein distance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance. The php function is: levenshtein()

Comment: @Rumplestiltskin. Forget my prior comment and review your code or any exit you had before, I'm getting the string you want with your code. "W123425".

Comment: @MarkBaker - I am looking for the identical consecutive characters in the string. I'm gonna to update the subject title. :)

Comment: @SalvadorP. - I'm getting **0**W12345 on my output. :'(

Comment: Many more duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+longest+common+substring